# Do I need Spring Security if I use JWT Authentication with Spring Boot?

Tags: spring, authentication, spring-security, spring-boot, jwt

I'm about to implement a token based authentication system with Spring Boot and Json web token. I have a frontend app built with Angular. My understanding is that once authenticated, all API calls from the angular app will send the token to the server to be verified before a response is sent back.

I'm wondering then how Spring Security would fit into the picture. It seems like it is no longer necessary if I just use the server to verify the token every time the frontend makes a call.

My question is whether or not Spring Security is required in this instance and if it is, what role will/can it play?

I would like to know from the outset before diving in. Thanks!

Comment: You should take a look at JHipster: AngularJs - Spring Boot - JWT

Comment: And what/how are you going to check the token. Also is the token the only thing you need to validate or do you also have different user types? If so how you are going to differentiate. You probably need more then just checking the token (how are you going to check the token validity?).